# To prove given set is basis for topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

An arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set

$A_a,_b=\bigg\{\dots,a-2b,a-b,a,a+b,\dots\bigg\}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq0.$ prove that the collection of arithmetic progressions

$B=\bigg\{A_a,_b|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\ and\ b\neq0\bigg\}$ is a basis for topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

any hint

Comment: how this topology is defined?

Comment: In the book Prime Number Records, the first chapter lists about 22 proofs that there are infinitely many primes.The last proof uses this topology to give a topological proof.

Comment: @ Michael Albanese .The Q that this is an apparent duplicate of, is not entirely identical. In the other Q, the set $A_{0,0}=\{0\}$ is open but here it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to note that $n\in A_{a, b}$ if and only if $n\equiv a$  $mod \ b$ and that solving two congruence equations will give you another congruence equation(if solvable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show to things: first that $\mathbb{Z}$ is covered by members of $B$, which is easy (hint: $b=1$ is allowed).

Second that every intersection of two basic sets $A_{a,b}$ and $A_{c,d}$ is a union of members from $B$ as well. In this case, $A_{a,b} \cap A_{c,d}$ is either empty (which is OK), or is again of the same form, which you can try to show using elementary number theory.

Comment: in the second step i am getting stuck

Comment: What have you tried? In fact, it is enough to show that if $x$ is in the intersection, then there is some $A_{e,f}$ with $x \in A_{e,f} \subseteq A_{a,b} \cap A_{c,d}$, which is weaker and easier.

Comment: i am  geting stuck in getting structure of intersection  of two basis elements in this case

Comment: Hint: if $x$ differs by a multiple of $b$ from $a$, and by a multiple of $d$ from $c$, what about the greatest common divisor of $b$ and $d$ ?